# Format one partition of usb hdd in macos format ensuring others partition remain untouched

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, format, journaled

My macbook air os has been crashed and need to reinstall the os but to take backup first.
Its only boot in safe mode only where it mount only its own format(journaled) external drives.
Ntfs drive did not mount in safe mode.
Its successfully format a pendrive with it own format i.e masos extended (case-sensitive,journaled). Where i can mount it and use for backup.

I have 500gb usb hdd. It comprises of 3 partitions as follows

1. System Reserved
2. Partition around 250gb with ntfs format
3. Partition around 200gb with ntfs format

**I want to format one of partition having ntfs format with macos format(macos Extended ,journaled) in macos high sierra without formatting full drive of my 500gb hdd.**

I want to only format one partition making sure that other partitions remain untouched or nothing happen to full hdd on formatting one partition.
Anyone have solution on how to do it. Please guide me.

Comment: Question edited. Can anyone give solutions

Comment: Some problems require more time to submit a solution.  If somebody knows the answer to your question it will be submitted.  The better quality the question is the faster the answer will be submitted.